# Get selected text from web elements

Tags: python, html, selenium, dom, css-selectors

hy is it possible  to get a text-only first text from td tag like 'Zubr Polish Lager 6%'

```
<td width="35%">Amber Storm Scotch Ale 6% 
                    <br/>SIZE/LIFE: 330ml <b>CASE</b>
                    <br/>UOS: 12
                    <br/>RRP: £1.59
                    <br/>POR%: 100.1%
                    </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

give id in your td element like this

```
<td width="35%"><div id="myId">Amber Storm Scotch Ale 6% </div>
                    <br/>SIZE/LIFE: 330ml <b>CASE</b>
                    <br/>UOS: 12
                    <br/>RRP: £1.59
                    <br/>POR%: 100.1%
                    </td>
```

and then you could just call your id

Answer (score 0):

better than use `</br>` u can use some `<p>` like

```
<td width="35%">
   <p>Amber Storm Scotch Ale 6% </p>
   <p>SIZE/LIFE: 330ml <b>CASE</b></p>
   <p>UOS: 12 </p>
   <p>RRP: £1.59 </p>
   <p>POR%: 1B00.1% </p>
</td>
```

And after in JS u can use firstElementChild.innerHtml for get the content of first p element.

But for that u need to add an id to ur `<td>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are **webscraping** use BeautifulSoup to get text HTML.

```
!pip install beautifulsoup4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """
<td width="35%">Amber Storm Scotch Ale 6% 
                    <br/>SIZE/LIFE: 330ml <b>CASE</b>
                    <br/>UOS: 12
                    <br/>RRP: £1.59
                    <br/>POR%: 100.1%
                    </td>
"""
BeautifulSoup(html).find('td').text.split('\n')[0]

Output: 'Amber Storm Scotch Ale 6% '
```

Comment: @AhsanNasir the other answers were more about HTML. Next time write that you are web scrapping because it wasn't mentioned in the question, so responders have to guess. I would be thankful for Accepting the answer.

Comment: hlo ill tried but it gives all the string